# dojox.mobile.Heading fixed bottom does not work

Tags: dojo

Can anybody construct a jsfiddle where a dojox.mobile.Heading is positioned with fixed="bottom"?

If I write the following Code (example from [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView.html)), the bottom Heading is not positioned bottom.

```
<div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">
  <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" fixed="top">View Header Bar</h1>

  <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" fixed="bottom">View Footer Bar</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is working for me (http://jsfiddle.net/G8QkC/53/):

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js">

    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"
    djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
            "dojox/mobile/Heading"], null);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">
         <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" fixed="top">View Header Bar</h1>

         <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" fixed="bottom">View Footer Bar</h1>

    </div>
</body>
```